# reduce with async/await returns too early

Tags: javascript, async-await, reduce

I have this method `loadAllCustomObjects` that calls the `async` function `loadCustomObject` (which does a `fetch`) multiple times and reduces the results:

```
export default class CustomObjectLoader {

    static async loadAllCustomObjects(elements) {
        const customObjectTypes = getCustomObjectTypes(elements);
        console.log('loadAllCustomObjects', customObjectTypes);
        const customObjectsData = await customObjectTypes.reduce(async (allData, elementType) => {
            allData[elementType] = await loadCustomObject(elementType)
            return allData;
        }, {});
        console.log('customObjectsData', _.keys(customObjectsData));
        return customObjectsData;
    }

}
```

However, `reduce` returns too early, and this is the log statements:

```
loadAllCustomObjects [ 'slider', 'twitter-share-button' ]
customObjectsData [ 'slider' ]
```

How can I make it complete all the objects in `customObjectTypes`?

Comment: I don't think that `reduce()` understands `async` functions. It expects the return value from the callback to be the accumulator value, and it won't do anything special when it sees a Promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array .reduce with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243468/javascript-array-reduce-with-async-await)

Comment: I solved it by using `reduce` in [`promise-async`](https://github.com/Kikobeats/promise-async) (=a Promise wrapper on `async`) instead.