# Async reduce returning promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of objects and I have to add one property on each of the objects coming from and async function

I am doing an Array.reduce to iterate on each of the elements and return just one result: One array of objects with the new property.

I have this

```
const res = await resultOne.reduce(async (users = [], user, i) => {
          let userName;
          try {
            let { name } = await names.getNames(user.id);
            userName = name;
          } catch (error) {
            throw error;
          }
          delete user.id;
          users.push({ ...user, userName });
          return users;
      }, []);
```

But I get the message

> Push is not a function of users

And this is because I think is a promise.

How can I handle async requests in a `reduce` or a `map`

Comment: If you can use a Promise library, you can use bluebird's Promise.reduce for this. I.E. `const res = await Promise.reduce( resultOne, async (users ...`.

Comment: @Paulpro thank you for your response, the thing is that i don't think that add another dependency is completely necessary for this case, this is something that I won't be repeating in the whole project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `users` is a promise. Don't [use `reduce` with `async` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243468/javascript-array-reduce-with-async-await/41243567#41243567). You could do something like `await users` in the first line, but that would be pretty inefficient and unidiomatic.

Use a plain loop:

```
const users = [];
for (const user of resultOne) {
    const { name } = await names.getNames(user.id);
    delete user.id;
    users.push({ ...user, userName: user });
}
```

or, in your case where you can do everything concurrently and create an array anyway, the `map` function together with `Promise.all`:

```
const users = await Promise.all(resultOne.map(async user => {
    const { name } = await names.getNames(user.id);
    delete user.id;
    return { ...user, userName: user };
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Bergi, I think the plain loop could work great and is even more readable, the number of users that will be passed through the loop are thousands. But I don't think that there is a way to avoid running all the loop to delete the user.id and add the user.name

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an async function, every time you return something it gets wrapped in a promise. To fix this you need to set the starting array as a promise and then await for the accumulator on each iteration.

```
const res = await resultOne.reduce(async (users, user, i) => {
  try {
    return [
      ...await users,
      { ...user, userName: await names.getNames(user.id.name) }
    ]
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}, Promise.resolve([]));
```

Comment: `await`ing the `users` later (after `await`ing the `getNames()`) will cause unhandled rejection warnings if one of the promises fails, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await

Comment: @Bergi I just updated my answer. Would this prevent/fix what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, they would be executed sequentially now. Still I don't think it's a good solution, it's confusing and easy to mess up :-)

Comment: Thank you @JossClassey for your response, I was following kind of this solution but I also agree that is not the more readable option.