# Canceling a chain of fetches if any fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I am working on an element that given a csv file from a user, takes rows of commands (adding, renaming, updating, removing different items) and executes them into a database on the basis that the commands are correct and legal.

Currently I try to validate each command before it is executed, but I can't catch every mistake like them having a typo when they add an ingredient, and then trying to reference that ingredient by it's correct name in a later row. Because of this, some commands will attempt to execute and fail. Is there a way to "mock-call" every command to ensure they work before actually executing each command?

Currently all commands are executed in this function, and I return true or false if any of the commands failed to execute (for now) which sets the state to either show a success message or not.

```
try {
    const { categories } = await fetchCategories();
    let results = await sheetData.reduce(async (accum: any, ingredient: any) => {
        let updateArray = await accum;
        // console.log(`>>> ${ingredient.command} ${ingredient.name}`)
        updateArray.push(await buildExecute(ingredient, categories));
        // console.log(`<<< ${ingredient.command} ${ingredient.name}`)
        return updateArray;
    }, Promise.resolve([]));

    const result = await Promise.all(results);
    return !result.some(val => val === false)
} catch (err) {
    return false;
}
```

inside `buildExecute`, I simply build up the endpoints to call, the data to include in the body, and the method for the fetch as such

```
try {
    const { result, error } = await (await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })).json();
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return false;
}
```

If there's a library that does what I'm looking for, I'm game to try it out, or if there's a built in method, that works too.

Comment: Most databases have "transactions" that do exactly that.

Comment: Yeah, I can see in the console tab whenever a fetch fails, however, I want to present it to the user through something on screen, not through the console tab.

Comment: Why are you talking to your database through the fetch api?

Comment: For the product I'm working on, the company developed an API that acts as an in-between for database interaction. Possibly for a level of "security" or something along those lines, and the endpoints also determine which parts of the database you interact with. I'm not too certain since I'm still new, and a new dev in general.

Comment: Btw, I recommend to [avoid using `reduce` with an `async` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57501330/1048572). Just make that a plain `for` loop. Also `const result = await Promise.all(results);` is pointless, as `results` currently already is an array of plain values, not of promises.

Comment: @Scoobidy-Bop Ask them to also provide an API that lets you run multiple interactions at once. Like georg said, this is a prime use case for transactions; also making only a single request to the backend would be more efficient.

Comment: @Ernesto He has. He uses them in the code.

Comment: @Scoobidy-Bop "*I want to present [the error] to the user through something on screen, not through the console tab*" - then don't have your `buildExecute` method swallow the error by logging to the console and only returning `false`, but have it return (or even throw) the actual error. Handle the error only by displaying it to the user, in the  part where your UI actually calls this method.

Comment: @Bergi I will talk to them about adding that as an endpoint. They've mentioned that they want customers to have an "all" or "nothing" experience when trying to upload a spreadsheet of commands.

Comment: Thank you @georg for the suggestion, I will make a push for that!

Comment: @Ernesto I will look into some of those methods. I've never worked with promises before, so this is all a learning experience for me

Comment: Here https://javascript.info/promise-api