# Run Promise all in an await for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have a nested array of `Promise` function. Eg:

```
let callSet = [
 [ func1 , func2 , func3],
 [ func4 , func5 , func6],
 [ func7 , func8 , func9],
]
```

the response of `await func1()` will be in below structure:

```
{
 data : [ {id: 1} , {id:2}],
 status: 400
}
```

I want to run it in a for loop so that they run in batch sequentially and incrementally load the data into array as they come in. Tried below code but I am lost on how to do it:

```
  const finalData = [];
  private asyncForEach(PromiseGroups): Promise<any> {
    return PromiseGroups.reduce(async (acc, cItem) => {
      const results = await acc;
      const res = await Promise.all(cItem) as any;
      finalData  = [...finalData  , ...[].concat(...res.map(r => r.data))];
      return results
    }, Promise.resolve([]))
  }
```

I would like to load it in as:

```
[ {id: 1}, {id:2} , {id: 3} ..... ]
```

and this should get updated as the Promise all is getting resolved

I want to wait till `func1 , func2 , func3` is resolved and then move to `func4 , func5 , func6` . and once I get data of `func4 , func5 , func6` , I want to push it with the data of  `func1 , func2 , func3`

Comment: Awaiting inside a reducer callback does not cause the `reduce` function to `await` for its callback

Comment: Can you elaborate *run in batch sequentially and incrementally*. I suspect you wan the function to so something more than what in ikhvjss answer.

Comment: @Newbie: Yes, you are correct, I want to wait till `func1 , func2 , func3` is resolved and then move to `func4 , func5 , func6` . and once I get data of ` `func4 , func5 , func6`` , I want to push it with the data of  `func1 , func2 , func3`

Comment: @JuanMendes: Can you please guide on the correct way please

Comment: Easiest way? Don't use `reduce`, just fill an array of promises using `for of`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243468/javascript-array-reduce-with-async-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```js
  private init(){
   let callSet = [
     [ func1 , func2 , func3],
     [ func4 , func5 , func6],
     [ func7 , func8 , func9],
   ];
   this.asyncForEach(callSet,this.fetchInBatch.bind(this) )
  }

  private asyncForEach(funcGrpList, execFunc) {
    return funcGrpList.reduce((p,funcList) => {
        return p.then(() => execFunc(funcList));
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }

  private fetchInBatch(pageGroupList) {
    return Promise.all(pageGroupList).then((res: any) => {
      this.finalData = [...this.finalData  , ...[].concat(...res.map(r => r.data))];
    }) 
  }
```

This should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Assuming the last array result is return directly because there is no need to wait for next loop to be finished.

```js
async function run(callSet) {
  const output = [];
  let prev = [];
  const len = callSet.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const array = await Promise.all(callSet[i].map(func => func()));
    const data = array.map(item => item.data);

    if (i === 0) {
      // no need to append item to output
      // just append item to previous array for next loop to use.
      prev.push(...data);
    } else if (i < len) {
      // append item to output from previous result.
      output.push(...prev);
      prev = [];
      // append data to previous result for next loop.
      prev.push(...data);
    } else {
      //last loop, just append data from previous result and current result
      output.push(...prev);
      output.push(...data);
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: @Newbie: Yes, you are correct, I want to wait till `func1 , func2 , func3` is resolved and then move to `func4 , func5 , func6` . and once I get data of ` `func4 , func5 , func6`` , I want to push it with the data of  `func1 , func2 , func3`

Comment: @ikhvjs I don't see how this usage of `reduce` can work with `async`. Reduce can be used with `async` by progressive wrapping, but is something very typo-prone so should be avoided.

Comment: @Newbie, I updated my answer. I misunderstand OP's requirement in the begining.

Comment: I have seen this answer change 5 times in 1 hour and the code is completely different and getting more convoluted each time. Please stop attempting to answer by trial and error.

Comment: @Newbie, it should be correct now. I changed the codes because OP changes his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This will call the execution sets in the requested order and timing and add the return data as soon as the group of promises returns

```
const finalData = [];

async function execute() {
  for (const set of callSet) {
    const resp = await Promise.all(set.map(f => f()));
    finalData.push(...resp.map(r => r.data).flat());
  }
}
```

Once `execute()` is called `finalData` will be updated asynchronously once for each 'row' of functions.

##### For future readers

`resp.map(r => r.data).flat()` is due to the specified promises payload. If someone needs just to pack the results together the code would be:

```
for (const set of callSet) {
  const resp = await Promise.all(set);
  finalData.push(...resp);
}
```

Comment: OP: I want to wait till `func1 , func2 , func3` is resolved and then move to `func4 , func5 , func6` . and once I get data of `func4 , func5 , func6` , I want to push it with the data of  `func1 , func2 , func3`. I think you misunderstand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the data in chunks but produce flat array of results, your easiest option is to use `async`/`await` syntax:

```typescript
interface Data {
  id: number
}
interface DataResponse {
  data: Data[];
  status: number;
}
type AsyncCall = () => Promise<DataResponse>;

/* ... */

const result: Data[] = [];
for(const chunk of callSet) {
  const chunkResult = await Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()));
  result.push(...chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data));
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAgXwNElkRXUwCUIBnAA4B7EPxR5CyEhjgVucANoBdANwEi-TGCr8K1etHX4W+MAE9BKAIL9zIBAGE4AGxfIAvMgAUASk8AfMgAClDCNMDiADwKfEKi4gHGBAD0AFTINMIIANbI4ghgwKLIaSkECAlgyPA5EABiVA6ePqQAjPq0DFAANMQkAEydhlD+HkF+FKHhkRAxsnEiYhBB4xohYRHiAHRQAsIuAG4Q3pJERDKYyBSK2KQU7UzIfXfk-QNMyj3rmtq6FAAWAAMQPWTF8yXwlTE1RgTQQbRatQa8O8bT6A183yk5xq8IGSLgdUaDm8AGY+gCsT9znCHGTCcTUQBWPoANmpONp8IBjJRpIA7H0AByc3FEOkIZl8kkIbwATj6bSBYvFkrZMtRbXRyDamOx4rxDgFmtJbQpuqpBrV8OFprlbVZuo51txkvl9rRQt1oppRGMhtSGRSWVy+QghWKIFK5XwBDgdmakqKJRocFAfhw6xcEGqCFcLgAyrmKLZ7E4CyoVEQvIoaYojQjno2CX1JWSvvXG7y2-Dpb2HGzO1yG5KTQOEHaJ-Lh0Q1AR1tCtMg9vwqC4wPJZNXa-OpDBhFBvEu8wALJp5YQwZD5tzFsD+M7nE8388gHJxdfVLxwADu6eqaYtggbYC2PN8cm2NNBG8a9xhqPxfAhGlVy-bZBF0U9vG2HCEAgz8N22GAXAwABZOAYIAD0CZBKO2S44CQgNkFMIh1j2HQoGjVCN2MUwCDTDNfHWbYwFPCAQG8KAaKXA4QJcYQAHMpKYoA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
/* mock section */
const fakeFunc = (id1, id2) => ()=>
  Promise.resolve({
    data : [{id: id1} , {id: id2}],
    status: 400
  });

const func1 = fakeFunc(1, 2),
      func2 = fakeFunc(3, 4),
      func3 = fakeFunc(5, 6),
      func4 = fakeFunc(7, 8),
      func5 = fakeFunc(9, 10),
      func6 = fakeFunc(11, 12),
      func7 = fakeFunc(13, 14),
      func8 = fakeFunc(15, 16),
      func9 = fakeFunc(17, 18)
      ;
      
/* /mock section */

async function main() {
  let callSet = [
    [ func1 , func2 , func3],
    [ func4 , func5 , func6],
    [ func7 , func8 , func9],
  ];

  const result = [];
  for(const chunk of callSet) {
    const chunkResult = await Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()));
    result.push(...chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data));
  }
  
  return result;
}

main()
  .then(r => console.log(r));
```

I you prefer to use the Promise API only, instead of `async`/`await`, then you can reduce into a promise like this:

```typescript
interface Data {
  id: number
}
interface DataResponse {
  data: Data[];
  status: number;
}
type AsyncCall = () => Promise<DataResponse>;

/* ... */

const result = callSet.reduce((p: Promise<Data[]>, chunk: AsyncCall[]) =>
   p.then(acc =>  
      Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()))
        .then(chunkResult => acc.concat(chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data))))
  , Promise.resolve([]));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAgXwNElkRXUwCUIBnAA4B7EPxR5CyEhjgVucANoBdANwEi-TGCr8K1etHX4W+MAE9BKAIL9zIBAGE4AGxfIAvMgAUASk8AfMgAClDCNMDiADwKfEKi4gHGBAD0AFTINMIIANbI4ghgwKLIaSkECAlgyPA5EABiVA6ePqQAjPq0DFAANMQkAEydhlD+HkF+gRohYRHiAHRQAsIuAG4Q3pJERDKYyBSK2KQU7UzIfUfk-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-IOUhLDoUD+mOaHGKYBDhpGMFSPBL7eFAn7DisHEuMIADminQaoQA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
/* mock section */
const fakeFunc = (id1, id2) => () =>
  Promise.resolve({
    data : [{id: id1} , {id: id2}],
    status: 400
  });

const func1 = fakeFunc(1, 2),
      func2 = fakeFunc(3, 4),
      func3 = fakeFunc(5, 6),
      func4 = fakeFunc(7, 8),
      func5 = fakeFunc(9, 10),
      func6 = fakeFunc(11, 12),
      func7 = fakeFunc(13, 14),
      func8 = fakeFunc(15, 16),
      func9 = fakeFunc(17, 18)
      ;
      
/* /mock section */

function main() {
  let callSet = [
    [ func1 , func2 , func3],
    [ func4 , func5 , func6],
    [ func7 , func8 , func9],
  ];

  const result = callSet.reduce((p, chunk) =>
    p.then(acc =>  
      Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()))
        .then(chunkResult => acc.concat(chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data))))
    , Promise.resolve([]));

  return result;
}

main()
  .then(r => console.log(r));
```

However, it is a bit ugly. It can be improved by extracting some functions:

```typescript
interface Data {
  id: number
}
interface DataResponse {
  data: Data[];
  status: number;
}
type AsyncCall = () => Promise<DataResponse>;

/* ... */

const combineWith = (acc: Data[]) => (chunkResult: DataResponse[]) =>
  acc.concat(chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data));

const process = (chunk: AsyncCall[]) => (acc: Data[]) =>  
      Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()))
        .then(combineWith(acc));

/* ... */

const result = callSet.reduce((p: Promise<Data[]>, chunk: AsyncCall[]) =>
    p.then(process(chunk))
  , Promise.resolve([]))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=44&ssc=18&pln=44&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAgXwNElkRXUwCUIBnAA4B7EPxR5CyEhjgVucANoBdANwEi-TGCr8K1etHX4W+MAE9BKAIL9zIBAGE4AGxfIAvMgAUASk8AfMgAClDCNMDiADwKfEKi4gHGBAD0AFTINMIIANbI4ghgwKLIaSkECAlgyPA5EABiVA6ePqQAjPq0DFAANMQkAEydhlD+HkF+gRohYRHiAHRQAsIuAG4Q3pJERDKYyBSK2KQU7UzIfUfk-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-xaMgSz8Hm1ReEhLioWAiwQCQVBIN43iCBQoSntECgqAEfSLsuyCrphG5bgEBKCB+sZfmpM4CPwV7Zq+Uh9JpcznuJKzrN4aZjkGUhLDoUD+uJknGKYBBQd+vjTFZNlQP2IkrOeLjCAA5t4ow-EAA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
/* mock section */
const fakeFunc = (id1, id2) => () =>
  Promise.resolve({
    data : [{id: id1} , {id: id2}],
    status: 400
  });

const func1 = fakeFunc(1, 2),
      func2 = fakeFunc(3, 4),
      func3 = fakeFunc(5, 6),
      func4 = fakeFunc(7, 8),
      func5 = fakeFunc(9, 10),
      func6 = fakeFunc(11, 12),
      func7 = fakeFunc(13, 14),
      func8 = fakeFunc(15, 16),
      func9 = fakeFunc(17, 18)
      ;
      
/* /mock section */

const combineWith = (acc) => (chunkResult) =>
  acc.concat(chunkResult.flatMap(x => x.data));

const process = (chunk) => (acc) =>  
      Promise.all(chunk.map(f => f()))
        .then(combineWith(acc));

function main() {
  let callSet = [
    [ func1 , func2 , func3],
    [ func4 , func5 , func6],
    [ func7 , func8 , func9],
  ];

  const result = callSet.reduce((p, chunk) =>
    p.then(process(chunk))
  , Promise.resolve([]));

  return result;
}

main()
  .then(r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: Many Thanks , I'll check this out and let you know. Meanwhile, I got another approach implemented here in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000182/sequencial-promise-all-call-with-a-variable-param . but I am stuck another problem. Can you please take a look at it . that would be really helpful.