# javascript - reduce array of async and sync functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, reduce

I am trying to `reduce` an array of both asynchronous and synchronous methods. I have two synchronous methods and one asynchronous methods that does some basic formatting an object. Since I have a mix of asynchronous and synchronous methods, I am using `async/await` with my `reduce`. The problem is my `formatName` method returns the error `Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined` because the `person` parameter passed in is a promise. I thought that since i use `await` in my reduce, the callback should return the actual value instead of a promise:

`const results = await fn(finalResult);`

My code works fine if i take out the synchronous methods from my array. But I need to reduce an array of both synchronous and asynchronous methods. Does anyone have tips on how I can get around this? My full code is below.

```
const formatName = (person) => {
    person.name = person.name.toUpperCase();
    return person;
}

const formatAge = (person) => {
    person.age += 10;
    return person;
}

// Async function  
const formatLocation = async (person) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    person.location = `${person.location.toLocaleLowerCase()}`
    return person;
}

const initialPerson = {
    name: "john",
    age: 35,
    location: 'USA'
}

const formattedStagesWithAsync = [
    formatLocation, // asynchronous
    formatAge, // synchronous
    formatName //synchronous
];

const process = async () => {
    const formattedPerson = await formattedStagesWithAsync.reduce(async (finalResult, fn) => {
        const results = await fn(finalResult);
        return results;
      }, initialPerson);

    console.log(`Formatted person - ${JSON.stringify(formattedPerson, null, 2)}`);
}   

process();
```

Comment: [Don't pass an `async function` as the callback to `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41243468/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions always return promises, so on subsequent iterations of the `.reduce` callback, the accumulator will be a Promise that you need to wait to resolve first.

While you could do

```
const accumVal = await finalResult
```

at the beginning of the callback, this would be a lot simpler by avoiding `reduce` entirely IMO.

```
const process = async () => {
  let person = initialPerson;
  for (const fn of formattedStagesWithAsync) {
    person = await fn(person);
  }
```

In the case that each of your functions returns the original object, like in the case here, that simplifies to:

```
const process = async () => {
  for (const fn of formattedStagesWithAsync) {
    await fn(initialPerson);
  }
```

(you're mutating the `initialPerson` in your original code too)

Answer (score -1):

`Promise` return `async` value but dont use `async` and `await` option for `Promise`, Just `return` it

[Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
const promiseHandler = () => {
    return new Promise((done, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done("hello");
        });
    });
}

promiseHandler().then(v => {
    console.log(v); // hello
});
```