# using async await with reduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have following

```
const imageField = ["logoUrl", "fullLogoUrl"]
const onCreate = async (submitData: any) => {
  const uploadImageField = await imageField.reduce(
    async function (acc: any, cur: string) {
      await acc;
      const url = await uploadImage(submitData.general[cur][0]);
      acc[cur] = url;
      return acc;
    },
  {}
);

console.log(uploadImageField);
}
```

this is my console.log

```
{
  logoUrl: "https://........"
}
```

only logoUrl field is show, fullLogoUrl is missing

Comment: reduce, much like forEach and map, will not wait on the promise to resolve before it continues.

Comment: i would map over the list of images, produce a list of promises, and await all of them (Promise.all or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `acc` on the second iteration is a promise object - that's why you `await` it. However, you still assign the `[cur]` property on that promise object, not on the promise result, and the implicit promise chaining of the `async` function as well as the explicit `await`s will just ignore properties on the promise object. You *could* fix this by [doing `acc = await acc;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243567/1048572), but really I **recommend not to use `reduce` with `async`/`await`** at all. A normal loop is much simpler and has no pitfalls.

```
const imageField = ["logoUrl", "fullLogoUrl"]
const onCreate = async (submitData: any) => {
  const uploadImageField = {};
  for (const cur of imageField) {
      const url = await uploadImage(submitData.general[cur][0]);
      acc[cur] = url;
  }
  console.log(uploadImageField);
}
```